# How to pull only certain fields with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to print all the fields that have England in them, the current code i have prints all the Nationalities into a txt file for me, but i want just the england fields to print. the page im pulling from is https://www.premierleague.com/players

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get("https://www.premierleague.com/players")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
players = open("playerslist.txt", "w+")


for playerCountry in soup.findAll("span", {"class":"playerCountry"}):
    players.write(playerCountry.text.strip())
    players.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to check if it's not equal 'England', and if so, skip to next item in list:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get("https://www.premierleague.com/players")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
players = open("playerslist.txt", "w+")


for playerCountry in soup.findAll("span", {"class":"playerCountry"}):
    if playerCountry.text.strip() != 'England':
        continue
    players.write(playerCountry.text.strip())
    players.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could just use [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) and a couple lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://www.premierleague.com/players")[0]
print(df.loc[df['Nationality'] != 'England'])
```

Prints:

```
               Player    Position                       Nationality
2        Charlie Adam  Midfielder                          Scotland
3              Adrián  Goalkeeper                             Spain
4        Adrien Silva  Midfielder                          Portugal
5     Ibrahim Afellay  Midfielder                       Netherlands
6         Benik Afobe     Forward  The Democratic Republic Of Congo
7       Sergio Agüero     Forward                         Argentina
9    Soufyan Ahannach  Midfielder                       Netherlands
10       Ahmed Hegazi    Defender                             Egypt
11         Nathan Aké    Defender                       Netherlands
14  Toby Alderweireld    Defender                           Belgium
15       Aleix García  Midfielder                             Spain
17           Ali Gabr    Defender                             Egypt
18         Allan Nyom    Defender                          Cameroon
19        Allan Souza  Midfielder                            Brazil
20          Joe Allen  Midfielder                             Wales
22      Marcos Alonso    Defender                             Spain
23        Paulo Alves  Midfielder                          Portugal
24     Daniel Amartey  Midfielder                             Ghana
25         Jordi Amat    Defender                             Spain
27       Ethan Ampadu    Defender                             Wales
28     Nordin Amrabat     Forward                           Morocco
```

Comment: Never used pandas, would you say it's better than BeautifulSoup?

Comment: @lammyalex it would not be appropriate to compare them. `pandas` is a large library for data manipulation and analysis. For HTML parsing, it actually uses `BeautifulSoup` internally to locate `<table>` elements on a page. If you are dealing with HTML tables and you need to filter, search, dump, load etc them, then `pandas` would make your life much easier.

Comment: That’s great! Thanks for clearing it up I’ll look into it and try it out. Thanks again.

Comment: +1 on using Pandas. I always find it easier to manipulate a dataframe than to have it iterate through tags of, table, th, tr, td, etc. If I see `<table>` tag, pandas is my default go to.